# How to disable CHUNKED transfer-encoding?

Tags: php, soap, chunked-encoding

I need to disable chunked transfer encoding, but I dont know whether I amsupposed to do it in the setup somehow or in the particular request..
I am sending data via SoapClient in PHP.

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient("https://ws-something.com/services/specialservice?wsdl",
              array('trace' => 1,
                    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE)); 
$result = $soapClient->Function($login,$xml,true);
```

I think the crucial part is the second parameter that needs to be sent with disabled chunked transfer-encoding. `$xml` contains a plain xml string, but might be possibly an object..

Can somebody help me with this, please?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the relevant Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding), HTTP/1.1 specifies that chunked encoding is always permissable, so the only way to ask a server not to use it is to downgrade the connection to HTTP/1.0.

The reason you need to is [PHP Bug#47021](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47021), a comment on which shows how to do this by creating a [Stream Context](http://php.net/manual/en/context.php), which can then be passed to the `SoapClient` constructor:

```
$http_context = stream_context_create([
    'http' => ['protocol_version' => '1.0']
]);
$this->client = new SoapClient(
    'http://example.com/some.chunked.send.wsdl',
    [
         'trace' => 1,
         'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
         'stream_context' => $http_context
    ]
);
```